# Define one column only when reading in a list of csv files?

Tags: r, readr

I'm reading in a list of files and combining into a single df with:

```
fi <- list.files(path = 'data', pattern = '*.csv', full.names = T) %>%  
  map_df(~read_csv(paste0(.)))
```

But this is hitting an error:

> Error: Can't combine `App ID` <character> and `App ID` <double>. .

Within the directory in question there are many files to read in and combine. I'd like to know if it's possible to define the column type for the problem field, `App ID` while reading in like this? E.g. `map_df(~read_csv(paste0(.), cols(`App ID = CHR`))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
 out <-  list.files(path = 'data', pattern = '*\\.csv',
    full.names = TRUE) %>%             
       map_df(~read_csv(.x) %>%
            mutate(across(everything(), as.character())) %>%
       type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, I had to update the error message above since it was using <> chars I had to escape them. It's the data types among the various csvs that are clashing. Any ideas? `Error: Can't combine `App ID` <character> and `App ID` <double>.`

Comment: @user14328853 please check the updte

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying here. Appreciate I never provided reproducible data but this doesn't work. It cannot get past the map_df() step since that's the step that throws the error. If I could somehow tell R to force field `App ID` to chr during read_csv that would do it. But reading the ?read_csv documentation I don't see how :/

Comment: @user14328853 why it doesn't work.  It is converting all columns to `character` within the `map` and binding.  So, it should work

Comment: Oh I see, yes I misread your code. Hm, let me try again...

Comment: Yep, it does work. Never realized or thought to mutate the df within the map_df function itself, thanks!